# moving/copying multiple files from one folder to another in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i need to create a condition that will move/copy selected multiple files from one folder to another i used openfile dialogue to browse files and set it to multiselect, i then created a label for the directory and filename the condition that i'm using right now only copies one selected file, i need to save all selected files at once.

this code is for insert attachments

```
Dim a As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog
 a.Multiselect = True
    If a.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        removeatt.Show()
        removeatt.Text = "Remove Attachment"
        fpath.Text = a.FileName
        fname.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(a.FileName)
        Dim file As String
        file = fpath.Text.ToString
        Label7.Text = file
        If fpath.Text = "-" Then
            removeatt.Hide()
        Else
            removeatt.Show()
        End If
    End If
```

and this is for the saving/copying part

```
 Dim dir As String
        Dim dir2 As String
        dir = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
        dir2 = Path.Combine(dir, "Site images and attachments/" & Label33.Text & "/")
        If Not Directory.Exists(dir2) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir2)
        End If
If fpath.Text = "-" Then
        Else
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(fpath.text, dir2 + fname.Text, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)
        End If
```

again, i need it to save the all the selected files

thanks

Answer (score 0):

in this code i will show you how to get all files path.
for saving part you have to split generated text and do the same.

```
   Dim a As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog

    Dim fname As String

    a.Multiselect = True
    If a.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        removeatt.Show()
        removeatt.Text = "Remove Attachment"

        For Each fname In a.FileNames
            fpath.Text = fpath.Text + IIf(fpath.Text.Trim <> "", "-", "") + fname
        Next

        Label7.Text = fpath.Text

    End If
```

Comment: thanks, thought i'm kinda lost when it comes to saving, i have no idea on how to do it.. also, the code is giving me a path that has a " - " in it, example, -C:\a.txt-C:\b.txt-C:\c.txt    is this okay?. and also the saving part..thanks

Answer (score 0):

for saving part you may split fpath.text with "-" character and put result into a string array like this:

```
dim filenames as string() <--- this is how to define string array
filenames = f.path.text.split("-")
for each file as string in filenames
       <-----   save file commands         
next
```